# Syntax error: 'Constant'

Tags: c++, winapi, constants

I am trying to learn some WinAPI programming on C++ trough this tutorial. 
http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/resources.html

The author first defines a constant in 'resource.h':

```
#define IDI_MYICON 101
```

and then he uses it in the .cpp file:

```
#include "resource.h"
IDI_MYICON ICON "my_icon.ico"
```

When I try to do that I get following error:
error C2059: Syntaxfehler: 'Konstante'
which translates into syntax error: 'Constant(the noun)'
What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Ok, as it seems that was a very dumb mistake of me. Well deserved -reputation. Thanks for replying!

Comment: I've no idea how WinAPI works, but the tutorial you link to says this should be a resource script, not a C++ source file.

Comment: What should `101 ICON "my_icon.ico"` actually mean as c++ code? Sure you're supposed to put this in a `.cpp` file?

Comment: You should really read this tutorial a bit closer: `You create resources in a resources script, a file with an extension of ".rc"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and then he uses it in the **.cpp file**
>
> ```
> #include "resource.h"
> IDI_MYICON ICON "my_icon.ico"
> ```

This is the problem.  The above code needs to be in a **.RC file** instead, and that file then needs to be compiled using a **resource compiler**, not a C++ **source code compiler**.

This line:

```
#include "resource.h"
```

Is valid in a .cpp file.  It is useful so the same `IDI_MYICON` define can be used when both creating the resource and when referring to the resource in source code.

This line:

```
IDI_MYICON ICON "my_icon.ico"
```

is NOT valid in a .cpp file, only in a .rc file!

Comment: How can I edit a .rc file then? Visual C++ 2010 Express doesn't have a built in one. And with resource eidtors like ResEdit, you can't change the code inside the .rc, you can only add a menu or an icon or whatever. And after I compile it into a .res file, can I still use it like the author of the tutorial does? Thanks for helping. Here's the link http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/menus.html

Comment: An .rc file is just a text file, edit it with whatever text editor you want. If you want to *visually* edit the content of the file, eg to design UIs and menus, or draw bitmaps/icons, or define string tables, then VS 2010 has built-in resource editors for those purposes (though I don't know if they exist in the *Express* edition, I have *Premium* instead). And there are plenty of 3rd party resource editors available for both .rc and .res files. And yes, you can link a precompiled .res file into your VS project, if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much, I now understand what it was all about, I just got completely mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

```
IDI_MYICON ICON "my_icon.ico"
```

is same as

```
101 ICON "my_icon.ico"
```

which has no meaning and it is syntactically wrong.

Comment: Okay.. Then I guess I am missunderstanding this because the tutorials that "this should work on any compiler."